# How do I allow traffic between security groups in Amazon VPC?

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I have a application security group and a database security group.  The instances are in separate subnets.

If I set both security groups to:

incoming - all traffic - source: 0.0.0.0/0
outgoing - all traffic - source: 0.0.0.0/0

then I am not able to get traffic to flow.  I am trying to rule out the security groups as the problem.  Are the above rules sufficient or do I also have to explicitly grant the security group ID as all traffic incoming/outgoing?

Comment: Well, are they able to talk to each other? Is there a problem?

Comment: They are not talking.  I have revised the question.

Comment: I would check your route table and network acls.

Answer (score 3):

There are two issues for instances talking to other instances within a VPC, and it sounds like you're getting the two confused.

A pretty common example is putting your web instances in a public subnet, and your database in a private subnet. (Scenario #2: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Scenario2.html)

You can try to control access with routing rules, but you probably don't need to.  So make sure that the two subnets can talk to each other.  (Rule #1:  Never mess with the default route)

For your web instances, you probably want to open port 80 - call this security group WebAccess, which allows everyone access to port 80, and maybe ssh is open to your IP.

For you database instance, you want the web instances to be able to talk to it, but nobody else.  So create another security group, call it DBAccess, and open up port 3306 (mysql).  Grant access to the WebAccess group, and now you should be good to go.

If you want to use ping to test, you can create a custom ICMP rule to allow it.  By default, ping is not enabled.

Comment: I understand there are Security Groups and Network ACLs and the route tables.  Are you saying there is some other mechanism?  My question is that if I have everything set to allow all ports on 0.0.0.0/0, should that let all traffic pass or do I need to explicitly allow on a specific port?  Obviously before I go live I need to restrict the access, but for now I am just trying to isolate the problem.

Comment: You don't specify what the "traffic" consists of.  Those are the two mechanisms for controlling flow and access, but you can't just test one of them: they both have to be right. More details on your route, your security group, and the tests you're performing are needed.